# How to Apply Class to GridMVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to apply some masking class to some columns.

```
 Razor


 @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Add(c => c.BrokerID).Titled("FEN Account ID").SetWidth(220);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Exm :

Html.Grid(x).Columns(col => {}).Attributes(@class => "usertable");
```

Comment: Hi Dilip.. Thanks for answering. But i'm not able to see the "Attributes" option  through Intellisense. And also, the code you have given will be applicable to all columns it seems. But i need to set the class to specific columns

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `Css` method to [add a class to a column](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20columns):

```
Columns.Add(x => x.Number).Css("hidden-xs")
```